# Why did user delete his answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

OK, I guess only he/she knows.

But it's strange ... I got an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201658/difference-between-nonserialized-and-xml-serialization-xmlignore) yesterday and it was a perfectly fine answer. And it was the only answer I had. Decided to wait a day before accepting it (per [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/how-much-time-should-i-wait-before-accepting-a-response-on-stackoverflow)). So I log back in today and it's gone.

I've seen answers deleted before if a "better" one has appeared or if there's a problem with the answer. However in this case ... no reason I can see to dump the answer.

Comment: Looks like the answer was technically incorrect. If the answerer realises this, the correct thing to do is delete the answer (or correct it, of course).

Comment: Now if only we can figure out why people answer in comments... :-)  You got your upvote anyway.

Comment: I made it a comment because I wasn't sure that this was the reason - I'm not an expert in the area of the original SO question.

Comment: @Neil -- I see, but it's still an answer -- and it's correct.  I did add a smiley.

Comment: @neil but now you know it's correct ...

Comment: You shouldn't have waited... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/38120#38120

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who can't see the original answer, it indicated that the NonSerialized attribute couldn't be applied to fields because it was meant for binary serialization, which is only partly true and it looks like the answer was deleted after someone commented that it was incorrect.  I've added what, I think, is the correct answer -- XmlIgnore is only processed by an XmlSerializer and if doing binary or SOAP serialization, you need to use NonSerialized.