# How long should/can I wait before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

If my knowledge is too limited to tell the difference between correct or wrong answers, how long should/can I wait before accepting an answer, vote up good answers and vote down wrong answers?

Can I wait for a period of 10 days or a month or for 100/ 500 views before selecting an answer when I am in dilemma? Or Can wait and depend on community to finally select the answer on voting?

Up to what time I should wait before accepting a correct answer while I am expecting better answers?

Please note that I believe that after asking a question, I must constantly work to find out the solution and ultimately accept/vote up the correct answer(s) or post the correct answer myself

Comment: I'd say, a minimum of a day before accepting any answer and only accept if an answer solves your problem satisfactorily, however long that takes.

Comment: If you can't tell the difference between a correct or wrong answer, maybe you should be asking a more elementary question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)

Comment: @Jeff When you've got an answer that solves your problem satisfactorily, that's when to mark it correct. Sometimes that might take mere minutes, sometimes many months (alas).

Comment: @Donal: The idea behind waiting a day is to "let your question soak" for a while.  Allow people to answer your question and possibly receive votes for their time. It's been my experience that people are more likely to view a new question when it doesn't have an accepted answer. If an answer pops up quickly that you like, upvote it and mark it in your head as "this will be the accepted answer." If that's still the case after a day, accept it. Either way, _always_ leave feedback as soon as you're able to give it.

Comment: @Jeff I can't really comment; my questions tend to be hard enough that I'm lucky if anyone answers them at all (well, answers sensibly) within 24 hours…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I wait for a period of 10 days or a month or for 100/ 500 views before selecting an answer when I am in dilemma? Or Can wait and depend on community to finally select the answer on voting?

You can wait as long as it takes.

Accept an answer as soon as you realize that it solved your problem, but not a moment sooner.

> Up to what time I should wait before accepting a correct answer while I am expecting better answers?

If none of the current answers is satisfactory, you're not forced to accept any of them.

If an answer is good enough but not perfect, wait a couple of days (as @JeffMercado suggested). After that, the probability of receiving new answer is almost zero anyway.

> Please note that I believe that after asking a question, I must constantly work to find out the solution and ultimately accept/vote up the correct answer(s) or post the correct answer myself.

That's a very healthy attitude. As long as you stick to it, you can't go wrong.

Comment: *If an answer is good enough but not perfect* - there is nothing to stop the OP editing the answer to make it 'perfect'.

Answer (score 4):

> how long should/can I wait before accepting an answer?

You **can** wait as long as you want, you **should** wait for the answer that solves your problem.

> vote up good answers and vote down wrong answers?

Yes, it's how SE works.

> Can wait and depend on community to finally select the answer on voting?

For me it's not the best solution. Of course most of the time, the most upvoted answer is the best. But it can happen that the aswer that fits the best to your question is not the most upvoted. So make your own choice based on what really help you.

> Up to what time I should wait before accepting a correct answer while I am expecting better answers?

If you are expecting better answers and nobody post new ones, then you can [set a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), it's a great way to revive a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can wait as long as it takes to get an answer that solves your problem, but remember – you can change the accepted answer by clicking on another answer’s checkmark at any time.

Comment: Why the downvote? This isn't wrong, I just tested it. Really.