# Should I wait for several subjective answers before accepting the best one?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Some kinds of questions have very objective answers, and it's clear when an answer truly answers the question. Other questions have several possible answers: sometimes the best answer is easy to identify, and sometimes it isn't. Still others kinds of questions may--by their nature--require purely *subjective* answers (perhaps these kinds of questions aren't as well-posed...).  Sometimes a question just generates useful discussion, but doesn't authoritatively answer the question because it lacks an objective answer.

What to do?

#### The *general* question has been answered here:

[How long should/can I wait before accepting an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136314/how-long-should-can-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)

I know I *can* wait as long as I feel is necessary to accept an an answer...but sometimes it is hard to know. Accepting an answer proclaims "I affirm this as the correct answer"—but sometimes I don't know if it really *is*.

#### --Specifically-- for the *it-might-be-right-but-I'm-not-sure* and discussion-type Q&As:

Should one wait for several answers or lots of votes before accepting one that *seems* the best? Should the question be re-worded to make it more objective (my hunch)? Or, is it best to just leave the answers unaccepted, just as a record of people's opinions and the discussion?

Comment: I'm assuming this is one of those discussion-based questions (#meta), but maybe somebody with more experience knows more than I do? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here are my thoughts:

- If the question is posed in such a way that you only receive subjective answers, then it's not a good question. Such questions fall under the umbrella of "soliciting primarily opinion-based answers" and should be closed as such. Yes, a subjective answer typically provides an opinion (personal).
- The system allows for unaccepting answers if another "more betterer subjective answer" pops up. So, feel free to make the choice and perhaps change your mind later. Ultimately you'll never know when the "most best subjective answer" will pop up.