# Feature to be reminded to accept an answer after a user-selected length of time

Tags: feature-request

**Related:**

- [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)
- [Remind new users to choose some answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers)
- [Should we respond to questions asked by users with 0% accept rates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79762/should-we-respond-to-questions-asked-by-users-with-0-accept-rates)

It's often not immediately clear that an answer to a question you've posed will prove "acceptable".  It may be necessary to test the advice provided by the answer to make sure it works; it may be a less than perfect solution (but ultimately the best one possible); or there may be another reason why question posers wish to wait some length of time before accepting a proposed answer.  After a while it can be quite time-consuming to go through all of one's unaccepted questions in order to remember which one(s) you were planning to take another look at.

I'm suggesting improving the current binary choice of a) putting the question in the back of your mind where it may or may not be thought about for the next month, or b) accepting a mediocre answer in order to avoid having unaccepted questions pile up.  I'd like there to be some way to specify, on a per-question basis and/or as a global per-user setting, that I'd like to be reminded to answer a question a given amount of time after an answer was provided.  I think this makes more sense as a per-question choice, maybe with a customizable default, because the nature of the question often determines how long it's useful to wait for the "right" answer.  It's also often dependent on the particular answer given.

I'm thinking that a dropdown box with choices like "1 day", "1 week", "1 month", etc. would be enough, but maybe something more customizable would be worth the trouble.  What do people think about this?

Comment: Did you mean "reminded to accept" as opposed to "reminded to answer"?  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Err yes actually.  Thanks!